# How can I set the Task Manager description for my program?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, taskmanager

I have a CLI program and I'd like to modify the description shown for it in Windows Task Manager.

I tried setting *Description* in the *Assembly Info*, but this only changes the .exe's *Properties > Details*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Under the Project properties, click Assembly Information and set the Title field.  You'll have to run without debugging to see the description display correctly in Task Manager.

Answer (score 0):

I think, if in AssemblyInfo:

```
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("")]
```

and

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("")]
```

both are set, then AssemblyProduct wins for Taskmanager description.
If only AssemblyTitle is set, then it's shown as description