# How to change name of console app as displayed in task manager?

Tags: c#, console

I am programmatically launching console applications. They all appear as `conhost.exe` in Task Manager.

How can I set a process name such that it appears as such in the task manager?

Example of how I'm setting up my process:

```
public static Process CreateMultiCoreExeProcess(int coreIndex, int coresToUse, string executableFilepath)
{
    //* Create your Process
    Process process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = executableFilepath,
            Arguments = coreIndex + " " + coresToUse,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true
        },
        EnableRaisingEvents = true
    };

    return process;
}
```

...as you can see there isn't an attribute that sets the process name (that I know of). I would like to be able to set the name of the process at the time that I create it.

DUPLICATE QUESTION REMARK: this is not a duplicate as attempted. The solution presented as a duplicate is for a STATIC name for the process, being set within project properties. I am running my process DYNAMICALLY (at run time) and would like to set the process name at that time.

UPDATE: I am convinced that this isn't possible. At least not in a realistic (i.e. permanent) way. I'm fairly certain we are "stuck" with the name as provided in the assembly information and it can't be programmatically changed in the Task Manager. This is unfortunate for my application, which is to spawn 10+ identical process executables. Sometimes I want to kill just one of them, but I can't determine which-is-which in the task manager because they all have the same name.

Comment: Can someone with higher permissions than me please remove the 'duplicate question' bar at the top? That question's answer is related to the DESCRIPTION, not the IMAGE NAME. They are not the same.

Comment: Is there any other way to approach this? Is it possible for you to use multi-threading in your program instead of starting multiple tasks? Or, if not, retain a collection of process IDs and terminate them that way? Using window names, in general, isn't always reliable.

Answer (score 5):

Use the line:

```
    Console.Title = "My Console Application";
```

to set the console name

And to set the name/description in task manager, it's been answered before quite a few times. Check this link [How can I set the Task Manager description for my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408496/how-can-i-set-the-task-manager-description-for-my-program)

Comment: My understanding was he wants to start a new process and give that a name, which I don't believe is do-able.

Comment: @Ahmed - your answer changes the DESCRIPTION not the IMAGE NAME.

Comment: Oh I get it.. I didn't understand your question correctly the first time. If I do find anything that answers your question I'll let you know

Answer (score 5):

You can use P/Invoke to change the process name after creating it. (As you cannot specify it when you create it. The default name is the name specified in the program.)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);
...
SetWindowText(process.MainWindowHandle, "Process Name/Title");
```

Edit: Looking around on the net, it appears you may need to wait 100ms or so before setting the name (either through `Thread.Sleep` or [`process.WaitForInputIdle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcdbkyt4.aspx) in the case of a GUI application).

Comment: I tried this in release and debug build modes. I used a 100ms timer before and after the call to SetWindowText(). No change to the Process image name in the task manager.