# Is it possible to set a display-name in task manager for a .NET Core web application?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have a .Net Core 2.0 web application and I would like to have the name displayed in task manager. It's currently showing `.NET Core Host`:

[image]

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408496/how-can-i-set-the-task-manager-description-for-my-program), but unfortunately it's not possible to change the assembly info, because this window is not even showing up (I assume this is because it's a .NET Core 2.0 application and not a .NET Framework 4.x application).

[image]

Is there another way to display the title of the application in task manager?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Taskmanager is totally oblivious to .NET and simply shows the name of the running executable. What you see is the "display name" of `dotnet.exe`, which is the stub used to run your .NET core (console) application, which is really just a DLL. That [(can) changes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/12/04/announcing-net-core-3-preview-1-and-open-sourcing-windows-desktop-frameworks/) with .NET 3.0 BTW (search for "Applications now have executables by default").

Comment: What you see in Task Manager isn't any display name, it's the title of the application's main window, or its executable name if there's no window. If you use `dotnet run` the application is the .NET Core host.

Comment: Try to set the title - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.title

Comment: @RandRandom I have set the title, but that only changes the title of the console that opens, not for task manager unfortunately.

Comment: The problem with building your application to a DLL and using the CLI to run your app is that the CLI will spawn a process for your code to be injected and run into. This means that it is the CLI tooling that controls this window.

Comment: This feature was requested and is tracked at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/2688 with milestone 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the application from the dll - no, there is no way as the DotnetCore-Hosting-Process is needed to run it.

If you deploy the application as a [self-contained application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs?tabs=vs156#simpleSelf) it will display the name you set your AssemblyName/Executable to:

.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>Hello World</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
   <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

Please also read up the consequences of publishing self-contained apps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to set display name by setting the `AssemblyTitle` value in .csproj file in .net core 3.1:

.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyName>Hello World</AssemblyName>
    <AssemblyTitle>Display Name</AssemblyTitle>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Nice. This way you can define one name (`AssemblyName`) for the binaries etc. and another name for display (`AssemblyTitle`).